# Scheduling Scrapy spider runs at an interval from script

Tags: python, scrapy

Let's assume i have a spider which i need to run multiple times

```
class My_spider(Scrapy.spider):
    #spider def
```

and i want to do something like that

```
while True:
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    deferred = runner.crawl(My_spider)
    deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
    time.sleep(180)
```

Is there even a way to do this? I have googled for past 12 hours i think and everything i tried didn't work, i either run into ReactorNotRestartable or something else. At this point i'm considering just writing a separate module which would just schedule console commands.

Comment: Why don't you try cronjob for that?

The following cronjob will execute the spider for every 5mins. 

`*/5 * * * * user cd /dir1/crawl_project/ && scrapy crawl spiderName`

For more information : [Scheduling tasks with cron-jobs](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

Comment: Thank you, this seems like it might just work

Comment: Oh, wait, Cron is a UNIX scheduler. This wouldn't work for Windows, right?

Comment: Yeah. What's your operating system? If windows, try this.
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/bring-linux-cron-like-power-to-windows/

Comment: Thanks, this might come in handy, but i don't think i want my client to setup any extra software. I think i just settle for os.system + schedule for this one

Answer (score 0):

use schedule module instead of time. Here's how you can do it

```
import schedule

schedule.every(1).minute.do(runner.crawl(My_spider))
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

this will run your crawl function every 1 minute. Learn more about this library [here](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)

Comment: this exact code returns

'TypeError: the first argument must be callable'

for my spider for the 'schedule.every(1).minute.do(runner.crawl(My_spider))' line